# To Automate MySQL dump

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-kernel, redhat

We wrote a simple script which backup's mysql dump and make a zip of dump file.  Please find the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
mysqldump -u Testuser -pTest123123## Testdbuser > mysqlnew.sql
mv mysqlnew.* dbbackup-$now.sql
zip -r dbbackup-$now.sql.zip dbbackup-$now.sql
```

The above script will take backup and rename the dump file but not able to zip the dump file getting error while zipping.  If i run the above zip command in bash it will execute.  Please find the below error.

```
*.sql    zip warning: name not matched: dbbackup-23_12_2014_15_29_40.sql)
zip . -i dbbackup-23_12_2014_15_29_40ackup-23_12_2014_15_29_40
```

Comment: why the `mv` step? Why not just `mysqldump ... > dbbackup-$now.sql`?

Comment: Hi Marc I tried before but it was appending alphanumeric character for a file name and getting file not found error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a mistake passing -r to zip. Since you need to zip a single file and don't need to travel the directory structure recursively.
And more, use pipe and don't create any excess files:

```
#!/bin/sh
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
mysqldump -u Testuser -pTest123123## Testdbuser | zip dbbackup-$now.sql.zip -
```